# L2 Bridging two Locations

Tags: networking, bridge

I'm not really experienced in Advanced Networking topics, so any help would be much appreciated. We have to temporarily bridge the Network (multiple VLANs) of two Buildings over the Internet for two weeks. We want to build a Layer 2 bridge. We do not have the same ISP on the two Locations.

I was told that this should be possible with VPLS. I have two Juniper SRX100h2 Devices which can handle VPLS. I cant find any good tutorial on how to configure the Layer 2 Bridge.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score -1):

I realized this case with OpenVPN and linux router on both sides. First i make "classic VPN"  network -- router -- internet -- router -- network and then i bridge "tun0 with eth0 together" on both sides and it work.